# difference between setting imageView smaller vs scaling image itself

Tags: android, iphone, image, resize, scale

I guess this question could be applied to both iphone and and android.

When I want to show smaller image,

1. I can set imageView to smaller size and let iphone handle the resizing to fit in the view.
   Or
2. I can actually resize the image itself.(using opengl call, or such as wrapper call createScaledBitmap in android)

I find option 1 is faster.
I always wondered why?

I also wondered the memory consumed by the image is governed by the size of imageView or image?

Comment: define 'resize the image itself'

Comment: hi Eugene... i am doing one task in which i want to make an image small..mean capture image of human and make some transform so it look like small image (like hobbit).. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is good question, I think when we resize the imageView to smaller that And image(UIImage) is greater that time memory consumption is more because of that image (UIImage) size is more respect to display in imageView. I think second option would be good to save memory .

Answer (score 0):

Image resizing need extra CPU cycles.So Its better to manually resize the image.